# How to test if module adds a method to before_filter when included by a controller class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, rspec

I'm wondering how would you solve this task

You want to refactor following code

```
class AController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :the_method

protected
  def the_method
  end 
end
```

into

```
class AController < ActionController::Base
  include TheModule
end
```

but as you are BDD enthusiast, you have to write the spec first

```
describe TheModule do
  context "when included" do
    it "adds #the_method as a before_filter" do

      # insert your code here

    end
  end
end
```

In other words the question is:
 How to write a spec that checks if TheModel#the_method is added as a before_filter when included in a class (presumably a controller class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
describe TheModule do
  context "when included" do
    it "adds #the_method as a before_filter" do
      instance = Object.new
      instance.class_eval do |klass|
        expects(:before_filter).with(:expensive_method)
        include TheModule
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Since we don't need to test the behavior of before filter. We can just test if it was executed properly.

Comment: Far simpler than my hacky solution :)

Comment: Object instance does not respond to #class_eval method. [14] pry(main)> instance.class_eval do
[14] pry(main)*   Include Foo
[14] pry(main)* end  
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_eval' for #<Object:0x1d1d8ccb>
from (pry):30:in `evaluate_ruby'
You probably want to use Class.new then newinstance.send(:include,ModuleName)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can check the presence of the method the callback calls as such.

```
@model.methods.include?('before_callback_method_name')
```

However this just checks the method the callback runs is present, not that its a specific type.

I cannot find a way to get a list of the callbacks for a  model.

Only option would be to test that the model does as its supposed to if the callback was present i.e if the callback reverses a string on update, check the string is reversed when updated.

*** EDIT ***

You can retrieve a list of callbacks like so :

```
@u._validate_callbacks
```

It returns a callback chain ,  which include there names and importantly , type.

```
>> u._validate_callbacks.first.class
=> ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback
>> u._validate_callbacks.first.kind
=> :before
>> u._validate_callbacks.first.filter
=> :validate_associated_records_for_sites
```

Should be able to test accurately if its loaded now.

Comment: Should work, the only thing I don't like here is that it adds dependency on internal ActiveSupport behaviour which can change and is already tested.